# How to do math calculation in node.js using mongodb document fields?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

I want to calculate BMI of a person using data from mongodb database and want to store result in same document as `"bmi":xxx`. My database looks like below.

database

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5d6c9cacfd9f1a1c30fed1c6"
  },
  "fname": "virat",
  "weight": 65,
  "height": 170
}
```

node.js(this not working)

```
app.put('/home/bmi',function(req,res){
  var data=[
    {
      "$project":{
        "bmi":{
          "$floor":{
            "$multiply":[
              {
                "$divide":[
                  "$weight",{"$pow":["$height",2]}
                ]
              },
              10000
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
  db.collection('users').aggregate(data,function(error,result){
    if(error) throw error
    console.log(data)
  })
})
```

as per calculation, bmi =floor((weight/pow(height,2))*10000)

Comment: does your aggregation query works fine w/o `app.put`?
And I guess you are using native mongo driver instead of mongoose?

Comment: yes I am using native mongodb .No my aggregate isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

add .toArray() after aggregation and you could use promise like this

```
    app.put('/home/bmi',function(req,res){
        var data=[
        {
          "$project":{
            "bmi":{
              "$floor":{
                "$multiply":[
                  {
                    "$divide":[
                      "$weight",{"$pow":["$height",2]}
                    ]
                  },
                  10000
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
        ]
        db.collection('users').aggregate(data).toArray()
        .then(r=>{
            console.log(r)

         }
         .catch(e=>{
             throw e
         })
    
    })
```